# Activity monitor doesnt display process name

Tags: cocoa, process

I have an application, when I see that application in "Activity Monitor" the applications Process Name is displayed nothing. Only the application icon is displayed.

I tried debugging this by getting processInfo of the app, I got the application name correct. Even tried with the "top" command, I got the application name correct. The target name and settings also shows the same, only the activity monitor got wrong.

Is it something I missed so that activity monitor is displaying nothing.

M

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer, it was the problem with CFBundleDisplayName in the info.plist. 
It was deleted from the info.plist so the app was not having a display name.

So whatever name you give in the CFBundleDisplayName it will used everywhere.

Thanks,
Mohsin